# Is co/complete category of monoid (or commutative monoid)?

Tags: category-theory, monoid

Let $Mon$ (resp., $CMon$) be a category of monoids (resp., commutative monoid) whose morphisms are usual monoid homomorphisms (resp., commutative monoid homomorphism). Is this category complete and/or cocomplete? If you know, could you give me any reference for this fact?

What I found currently is [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242852/does-the-functor-treating-a-monoid-as-a-category-preserve-colimits-and-limits) and the author claims that both categories are complete/cocomplete for all small limits/colimits. However, I have difficulties finding references for this fact.

Comment: It is true that those categories are complete and cocomplete. The case of colimits is a little more difficult, but you can at least easily check that the set-wise limit of a diagram of monoids has an obvious monoid structure, and that this gives a limit in the category of monoids. For colimits, you might be interested in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/colimits+in+categories+of+algebras for a general case of algebras over a monad.

Comment: @CaptainLama Thank you very much!! That's what I'm looking for!